# Modify a nested list recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I have a `nested list` of `string / list(str)` like:

`li = [["1", ["2", "3"]], "4", [[["5", "6", "7"], "10", "11"], ["12", "13", "14"]]]`

I want as output a list with the same nested structure, but all the sublists that satisfy the conditions:

- `len(sublist) in {2, 3}`
- all elements in list are `<str>`
  (see the function `to_true`)

must be replaced with a `True`.
The expected output should be

`[["1", True], "4", [[True, "10", "11"], True]]`

How can I write a function that (possibly recursively) does it? 
Another possible way is also modifying inplace the input list after a `deepcopy`.

```
def to_true(o) -> bool:
    # True if o is a 2/3 element list/tuple containing only <str>
    if not isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
        return False

    if len(o) not in {2, 3}:
        return False

    return all(isinstance(i, str) for i in o)
```

`>>> func(li)`

`[["1", True], "4", [[True, "10", "11"], True]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
def my_func(my_list):
    result = []
    for i in my_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            # Recursively transform the sublist
            result.append(my_func(i))
        else:
            result.append(i)
    # Check if the result should be replaced with True
    if all(isinstance(i, str) for i in result) and len(result) in {2, 3}:
        return True
    return result

my_list = [["1", ["2", "3"]], "4", [[["5", "6", "7"], "10", "11"], ["12", "13", "14"]]]

print(my_func(my_list))
```

output:

> [['1', True], '4', [[True, '10', '11'], True]]